# tar (child): phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages-tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I'm using amazon web services for the first time, I'm using the ec2 Amazon Linux instance for this. What I want to do is, I want to install PhpmyAdmin over there, so for that first of all I have already installed php, mysql and apache. After that I was trying to install phpmyAdmin. So for that I fired following commands:

```
cd /var/www/html
```

sudo chown ec2-user

wget http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/3.4.1/phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages.tar.bz2

So after this I tried to extract phpmyadmin with following command

```
tar -jxf phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages-tar.bz2 -C /var/www/html
```

After firing that command I got the following errors:

*tar (child): phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages-tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now*

Please help me out with this :-). Every comments and helps are appreciated :-). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding ./ before the filename to indicate the file is located in the current directory?

```
tar -jxf ./phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages-tar.bz2 -C /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -jxf phpMyAdmin-3.4.1-all-languages.tar.bz2
```

This command worked.

Comment: This should be a comment below the answer you took the command from, not an answer.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Hello @dg99 I have already done Vote up, after that :) I said thanks to him for spending his time :-)